# In JS how to print string in while loop multiple times?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

```
    var loop = function(){   
    while(loop<3){   

   console.log("I'm looping!");      
    loop++;    
  }    
};   

loop();
```

I tried in this way... i need to print above message 3 times... how to do it ??

Comment: Hint: `loop` is the name of the function; you're comparing your function to `< 3` at the start of your loop. Look up `for` loops in JavaScript...

Comment: Don't use `loop` for both the function and loop variable.

Comment: @meagar I need to do it using while loop only... So i can't go fr for loop..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use a while loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your function definition is correct.

You could also self-invoke your function like this

```
var func = function() {
}(); // notice () right here, without another call like func();
```

What about loops, there are several. Take a look.

```
var times = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < times; i += 1) {
  console.log('I\'m looping! #'+i);      
}   

// or
console.log("\n");

var o = 0;
while (o < times) {
  o += 1;
  console.log('I\'m looping! #'+o);      
} 

// or
console.log("\n");

var u = 0;
do
{
  u += 1;
  console.log('I\'m looping! #'+u);      
}
while (u < times)
```

Comment: this will print 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable name , is the same of your function

```
 var loop = function(){   
var l = 0
    while(l<3){   

   console.log("I'm looping!");      
    l++;    
  }    
};   

loop();
```

Comment: declaring `loop` the variable inside `loop` the function would work perfectly fine as well (but I agree it's less confusing this way :-)

Comment: thnks @kamus... It works